# Push, pull, fetch code was denied in git extension app

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-extensions

If I use git bash I can do that with command line but when I do on Git Extension application it encounter problem same picutre

[image]

with `git remote -v` it show format

```
origin  git@github.com:username/repository.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:username/repository.git (push)
```

I also add public key into github.

Can anybody help me solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: That's sometimes raised due to network connectivity issue or slow network comnection. Make sure network is up.

Comment: Also if you are trying to pull from server, you should do `git pull origin <branch name>`

Comment: @SumeetKumar it still not yet success. I think not of network connection because I use git bash not problem.

Comment: Which branch you are trying to pull ?

Comment: @SumeetKumar it's branch_home

Comment: Do `git pull origin branch_home` when you are in local git repo

Comment: @SumeetKumar yes.

Comment: Well this should have worked.
Update your question with output of `git branch`

Comment: what does this mean? Even when i switch another branch it still encounter that problem.

Comment: In gitextensions settings, do you have openssh as ssh tool selected? That should not be putty

Comment: - What is GE version? - What is git version? - Do you use putty or openssh?

Comment: @Philippe, RussKie I change to OpenSSH from PuTTY to solved my problem, thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help of everyone, I solved my problem by change tool ssh from putty to openssh.

[image]